# combining linear and random effect smooth in mgcv for plotting

Tags: r, mgcv, gratia

Consider a simple GAM (using `mgcv`) with one linear smooth and one random intercept term like this:

```r
gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2, bs="re"), method = 'REML', 
    family = 'gaussian', data = my.data)
```

I know I can use `gratia::smooth_estimates()` to get nicely spaced predictions for `x1`, and the random effects for each level of `x2`, all in one data frame. Is there a neat way of producing the smooth estimates for `x1` for each level of `x2` all in one place for plotting, i.e. taking each value for `x1` and adding on each value of `x2` to give n(x2) smooths which stack on each other when plotted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be prediction depending on whether you want to include or exclude the model constant term (and from the example I would argue it doesn't matter if you include the intercept).

If so, you can use the `fitted_values()` function in {gratia} to generate the values you want by providing it with a suitable data slice:

```r
library("gratia")
library("mgcv")
m <- gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2, bs = "re"), method = "REML", 
         family = gaussian(), data = my.data) 
ds <- data_slice(m, x1 = evenly(x1, n = 100), x2 = evenly(x2))
fv <- fitted_values(m, data = ds, scale = "response")
```

If you really want to exclude the constant term, then you can *exclude* or *select* any combination of terms in the model, including parametric terms using the `exclude` or `terms` arguments respectively to `predict.gam()` (which `fitted_values()` passes on for you). You do have to be careful to spell the names of the terms correctly. If in doubt, run `summary()` on your model and note how mgcv refers to the terms.

For example, to remove the intercept, we modify the above `fitted_values()` call to

```r
fv <- fitted_values(m, data = ds, scale = "response", exclude = "(Intercept)")
```

Using `exclude` (or `terms`) what can produce estimated values for any additive combination of model terms for the covariate values supplied by to the function. `fitted_values()` is just a nice wrapper around `predict.gam()`, which also produces the appropriate credible interval for you - if you ask for `scale = "response"`, it fits on the link scale and then back transforms the estimates and their uncertainty band to the response scale using the inverse of the link function.

Comment: Just checking this line:

`ds <- data_slice(m, x1 = evenly(x1, n = 100), x2 = evenly(x2))
fv <- fitted_values(m, data = ds, type = "response")`

Should `type = 'response'` be `scale = 'response'`

Comment: @MikeDunbar Sorry Mike, yes, it should be `scale`

Comment: Addendum - if I had a model with several continuous smooths and one bs='re' smooth - let's say this is time series data with other covariates for a series of monitoring sites and the random intercept (x2 in the above) is for a site ID, is there an easy way to also make a prediction for the average site without having to combine the other smooths by hand - if I drop x2 from data_slice above then I think I'll get a prediction for the first value in x2 which isn't quite what I'm after. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to exclude a random effect or any smooth, just add it (concatenate) to the `exclude` vector of term labels. Say your model was a HGAM (Pedersen et al 2019) like `s(x1) + s(x2, bs = "re") + s(x1, by = x2)`, then it would be easier to just use `terms = "s(x1)"` instead of `exclude` (`terms` does the opposite of `exclude`).

Comment: @MikeDunbar The reason `data_slice()` includes one level of the random effect if you don't specify `x2` in the data slice, is that `predict.gam()` requires all variables in the model to be present (usually anyway) and I felt it was safer to just add a default to explicitly condition predictions on